# Deriving from a class that has Annotation @PostConstruct

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, inheritance, annotations

If you have a parent class which uses the `@PostConstruct` annotation and you create a child class that derives from it. Will the `@PostConstruct` method be called automatically each time an instance of the child class is created? since that `@PostConstruct` method is called each time an instance of the the parent is created.

I Know that in the child class it calls `super();` for us automatically without us having to call it.

im just not sure if the `@PostConstruct` annotation is automatically called if that child class calls the `super();` constructor.

Comment: Put `println()` calls in both methods, fire up your app, and see what gets printed.

Comment: Like @millimoose suggested, you can test it yourself and answer your question. I think it will be good for others in the future.

Comment: This might depend on what's doing the injecting. I think `@PostConstruct` is recognized by both [tag:cdi] and [tag:ejb3], and perhaps also by other frameworks, and these could conceivably have different behaviour. What framework are you using here?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

After testing this scenario, the `@PostConstruct` method in the base class WILL automatically be called.

The flow goes like this:

1. When the child class is created, you are in the constructor of the child class, you then are forced into the parent class automatically.
2. Once the parent class constructor is done you are sent back to the child class' constructor.
3. Once the child class constructor is done you are automatically sent to the PARENT classes `@PostConstruct` method

Comment: In my test, if you're overriding a super's `@PostConstruct`, then the child's is called first. If you're not overriding, then the parent's is called first.