# When overriding the @PostConstruct method, is the method in the parent called when a child is created?

Tags: java, spring

Ran into this question:

[Why @PostConstruct method in parent class execute after @PostConstruct method in child class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36862079/why-postconstruct-method-in-parent-class-execute-after-postconstruct-method-in)

But when I took the same code and put it in a simple Spring Boot app, what I get is:

```
Parent-----constructor
Child-----constructor
Child-----PostConstruct
```

showing that the parent @PostConstruct method is NOT called when a child is instantiated.

What explains the difference ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED**

The other question is wrong.

Since the child `@PostConstruct` method overrides the parent `@PostConstruct` method, Spring is smart enough to only invoke the method once, and since the child method doesn't call `super.init()`, only the output from the child is printed.

```
Parent-----constructor
Child-----constructor
Child-----PostConstruct
```

If you rename one of the 2 methods, so the child `@PostConstruct` method doesn't override the parent `@PostConstruct` method, then both are executed.

```
Parent-----constructor
Child-----constructor
Parent-----PostConstruct
Child-----PostConstruct
```

When I ran the code, the parent `@PostConstruct` method was called first.

Comment: That's exactly what I expected. You can also make the methods private instead of renaming them, though that might make it a bit confusing. I wonder how the OP of that post managed to post the wrong output.